# How to streamline loading of objects with child objects

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an application that is broken into modules. In the user management module, I load up the users into their objects, including which modules they are able to access and their level of access.

Below is a screenshot of the user list. As you can see, if the user has access to a module then the triangle on the button highlights orange. Clicking on it will display the users module security levels.
[image]

This is a virtualized `DataGrid`, so not all items in the grid are updated graphically.

To start with I used the following code which just popped the complete collection of module objects into the user accounts.

```
    ObservableCollection<User> _users = new ObservableCollection<User>();

    public void LoadUsers()
    {
        var users = SelectUsers();
        foreach (var u in users)
        {
            _users.Add(u);
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<User> SelectUsers()
    {
        var userModulesLookup = GetModules();
        var userModuleLevelsLookup = GetUserModuleLevels().ToLookup(x => Tuple.Create(x.User_ID, x.Module_ID));

        clsDAL.SQLDBAccess db = new clsDAL.SQLDBAccess("AFX_USERS");
        db.setCommandText("SELECT * FROM USERS");

        using (var reader = db.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                var user = new User();
                var userId = NullSafeGetter.GetValueOrDefault<int>(reader, "USER_ID");
                user.User_ID = userId;
                user.Username = NullSafeGetter.GetValueOrDefault<string>(reader, "USERNAME");
                user.Name = NullSafeGetter.GetValueOrDefault<string>(reader, "NAME");
                user.Phone_Mobile = NullSafeGetter.GetValueOrDefault<string>(reader, "PHONE_MOBILE");
                user.Email = NullSafeGetter.GetValueOrDefault<string>(reader, "EMAIL");
                user.Status = NullSafeGetter.GetValueOrDefault<int>(reader, "STATUS");

                user.UserModulesFull = new ObservableCollection<UserModuleFull>(userModulesLookup);

                //**************** BIT OF A BOTTLENECK *************************
                foreach (var mod in user.UserModulesFull)
                {
                    mod.UserModuleLevelsFull = new ObservableCollection<UserModuleLevelFull>(userModuleLevelsLookup[Tuple.Create(userId, mod.Module.Module_ID)]);
                }
                //**************************************************************

                yield return user;
            }
        }
    }


    private static IEnumerable<Users.UserModuleFull> GetModules()
    {
        foreach (Module m in ModuleKey._module_objects)
        {
            var user_module = new Users.UserModuleFull(m);
            yield return user_module;
        }

    }
    private static IEnumerable<Users.UserModuleLevelFull> GetUserModuleLevels()
    {
        clsDAL.SQLDBAccess db_user_module_levels = new clsDAL.SQLDBAccess("AFX_USERS");
        db_user_module_levels.setCommandText(@"SELECT * FROM USER_MODULE_LEVELS");
        using (var reader = db_user_module_levels.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                int u_id = NullSafeGetter.GetValueOrDefault<int>(reader, "USER_ID");
                int m_id = NullSafeGetter.GetValueOrDefault<int>(reader, "MODULE_ID");
                int ml_id = NullSafeGetter.GetValueOrDefault<int>(reader, "MODULE_LEVEL_ID");
                int mla = NullSafeGetter.GetValueOrDefault<int>(reader, "MODULE_LEVEL_ACCESS");

                yield return new Users.UserModuleLevelFull(u_id, m_id, ml_id, mla);
            }
        }
    }
```

However I now only want to pop in specific modules associated with them and in turn associated module levels.

I'd like to set the loading of module information up on another thread, that runs after the users have been loaded. Loading the users first, modules second so the UI is updated as quickly as possible, then load the module levels.

This is what I was thinking of, but the task is quite slow and doesn't update the UI properly. Meaning if I scroll through the grid while the modules are still being loaded it isn't updating it fluidly as I'd expect.

```
    ObservableCollection<User> _users = new ObservableCollection<User>();

    public void LoadUsers()
    {
        var users = SelectUsers();
        foreach (var u in users)
        {
            _users.Add(u);
        }

        var usersWithSecurity = GetUserWithSecurity();
        var userModules = GetUserModules().ToLookup(x => x.Key);
        var userModuleLevelsLookup = GetUserModuleLevels().ToLookup(x => Tuple.Create(x.User_ID, x.Module_ID));

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            if (usersWithSecurity.Any())
            {
                foreach (int User_ID in usersWithSecurity)
                {
                    User user = _users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.User_ID == User_ID);

                    if (user != null)
                    {
                        var user_modules_collection = userModules[User_ID];
                        if (user_modules_collection.Any())
                        {
                            foreach (var user_module_pair in user_modules_collection)
                            {
                                Module module = ModuleKey._module_objects.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Module_ID == user_module_pair.Value);
                                if (module != null)
                                {
                                    UserModuleFull userModule = new UserModuleFull(module);
                                    user.UserModulesFull.Add(userModule);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        })
        .ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            if (usersWithSecurity.Any())
            {
                foreach (int User_ID in usersWithSecurity)
                {
                    User user = _users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.User_ID == User_ID);
                    if (user != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var user_module in user.UserModulesFull)
                        {
                            user_module.UserModuleLevelsFull = new ObservableCollection<UserModuleLevelFull>(userModuleLevelsLookup[Tuple.Create(User_ID, user_module.Module.Module_ID)]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
    public IEnumerable<User> SelectUsers()
    {
        clsDAL.SQLDBAccess db = new clsDAL.SQLDBAccess("AFX_USERS");
        db.setCommandText("SELECT * FROM USERS");

        using (var reader = db.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                var user = new User();
                var userId = NullSafeGetter.GetValueOrDefault<int>(reader, "USER_ID");
                user.User_ID = userId;
                user.Username = NullSafeGetter.GetValueOrDefault<string>(reader, "USERNAME");
                user.Name = NullSafeGetter.GetValueOrDefault<string>(reader, "NAME");
                user.Phone_Mobile = NullSafeGetter.GetValueOrDefault<string>(reader, "PHONE_MOBILE");
                user.Email = NullSafeGetter.GetValueOrDefault<string>(reader, "EMAIL");
                user.Status = NullSafeGetter.GetValueOrDefault<int>(reader, "STATUS");

                yield return user;
            }
        }
    }

    private static IEnumerable<int> GetUserWithSecurity()
    {
        clsDAL.SQLDBAccess db_user_module_levels = new clsDAL.SQLDBAccess("AFX_USERS");
        db_user_module_levels.setCommandText(@"SELECT USER_ID FROM USER_MODULE_LEVELS Group By USER_ID");
        using (var reader = db_user_module_levels.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                int u_id = NullSafeGetter.GetValueOrDefault<int>(reader, "USER_ID");

                yield return u_id;
            }
        }
    }

    private static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, int>> GetUserModules()
    {
        clsDAL.SQLDBAccess db_user_module_levels = new clsDAL.SQLDBAccess("AFX_USERS");
        db_user_module_levels.setCommandText(@"SELECT USER_ID, MODULE_ID FROM USER_MODULE_LEVELS Group By USER_ID, MODULE_ID");
        using (var reader = db_user_module_levels.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                int u_id = NullSafeGetter.GetValueOrDefault<int>(reader, "USER_ID");
                int m_id = NullSafeGetter.GetValueOrDefault<int>(reader, "MODULE_ID");

                yield return new KeyValuePair<int, int>(u_id, m_id);
            }
        }
    }

    private static IEnumerable<Users.UserModuleLevelFull> GetUserModuleLevels()
    {
        clsDAL.SQLDBAccess db_user_module_levels = new clsDAL.SQLDBAccess("AFX_USERS");
        db_user_module_levels.setCommandText(@"SELECT * FROM USER_MODULE_LEVELS");
        using (var reader = db_user_module_levels.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                int u_id = NullSafeGetter.GetValueOrDefault<int>(reader, "USER_ID");
                int m_id = NullSafeGetter.GetValueOrDefault<int>(reader, "MODULE_ID");
                int ml_id = NullSafeGetter.GetValueOrDefault<int>(reader, "MODULE_LEVEL_ID");
                int mla = NullSafeGetter.GetValueOrDefault<int>(reader, "MODULE_LEVEL_ACCESS");

                yield return new Users.UserModuleLevelFull(u_id, m_id, ml_id, mla);
            }
        }
    }
```

At the moment the UI side of things can wait, really interested in how I can speed things up.

Comment: I'd start with moving `usersWithSecurity`, `userModules`, 'userModulesLevelsLookup` down, under `StartNew`, and remove all `Any()` checks, they are useless and in some cases (for `userWithSecurity` for example) result in additional database query.

Comment: Thanks Evk, that makes sense, I'll do this when I get in tomorrow